# Not able to boot into Windows after stopping chkdsk abruptly (started and stopped in cmd)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, uefi, hiren

I have an Acer Predator Helios 300. Boot Mode have 2 options: **UEFI and Legacy**. And the system has 2 drives: A 128G SSD and a 1TB HDD. And the system is not able to boot up.

What I've tried:

1. **Automatic Repair** - Ends on a black screen witn a cursor.
2. **Clean Windows Install** - Ends on a blue screen with a cursor.
3. **Disabled Secure Boot**.
4. **Made HirensBootableCD USB** - Stuck on Predator logo screen.
5. **Made UbuntuLive cd** - Booted OK. Found that HDD file system is corrupt as I was not able to mount it. Tried `ntfsfix`, `fsck`, `e2fsck`. Could not fix.
6. Right now I am **cleaning this disk** which will take about 7 hours.
   Yesterday I could see bad sectors rising up from 320 to 345 in 20 minutes. And today it shows "Disk is likely to fail soon."

If I am able to mount my SSD without any issue and I can access its contents also and my Windows 10 OS is also in my SSD then why am I not able to boot up the device?

And will I be able to boot up or perform a clean Windows install after I am done with the HDD clean process?

Or would this warning (likely to fail soon) go away after cleaning?

Please let me know if any other information is requried.

Comment: I would honor the warning and replace the drive. When we see this at clients, we replace the drive right away. Even if you get it running, you can not depend upon it.

Comment: Cleaning disks is usually the term describing securely wiping all of the data from them. It does not repair the drive, or make bad sectors go away. In fact, for a dying drive, a cleaning will kill it more, faster. But, you never said which of these two drives you're cleaning, and which one you're trying to load Windows on, and how your system was configured before. We need more information to answer your question, and you can only ask ONE question per post, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@John: thanks. I did the same. I replaced my HDD with SSD as i could not depend on the drive to retain my data. Although my SSD was intact only its file system was corrupted. I fixed it by booting from a live usb Ubuntu.
@music2myear if you are so kind to note that i asked more than one question, then please also note that i'd also described that I'm trying to load windows on my SSD and I'm trying to clean my HDD.
Please read the question again.
Guys like you have made people like me not to ask anything over here.